# Using numbers within a string

Tags: batch-file, file-io, sum

This is a request for a solution using a batch file.  I have a file containing two columns - a name string and a data string.  The data string contains both letters and numbers.  I would like to extract and sum the numbers.  For example, the data string could be `C18H26ClN3O`.  The correct sum is `49 (18+26+1+3+1)`.  This is a molecular formula for a chemical so please note that Cl represents a single elements and an implied value, in this example, of 1.  There are other possible two letter combinations but no three letter combinations.  The O at the end also has an implied value of one.  I am not a programmer but I suspect there are easier ways to solve this problem than doing this with a batch file.  However, I need to do it in a batch file.  The input data file would look like this:

```
hydroxychloroquine C18H26ClN3O  
ibuprofen C13H18O2  
crestor C44H54CaF2N6O12S2  
aspirin C9H8O4
```

(each record is one line, carriage return)

The output file would look like this:

```
hydroxychloroquine 49
ibuprofen 33
crestor 121
aspirin 21
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    set "letters=a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z"


    for /f "tokens=1,2 usebackq" %%a in ("chemical.txt") do (

        :: Remove the lowercase letters from string
        set "form="
        for /f %%z in ('cmd /d /q /u /c "echo %%~b" ^| more ^| findstr /v  "%letters%"') do (
            set "form=!form!%%~z"
        )

        :: Separate elements with spaces
        for %%z in (%letters%) do set "form=!form:%%z= %%z!"

        :: For each element, if it has number add , if not add 1
        set "sum=0"
        for %%z in (!form!) do (
            set "elem=%%z" & set "elem=!elem:~1!"
            if defined elem ( set /a "sum+=!elem!" ) else ( set /a "sum+=1" )
        )
        echo %%a !sum!
    )

    endlocal
```

Comment: +1, Very clever and effective method to iterate characters and remove lowercase characters - Totally out of the box thinking. The remainder can be greatly simplified. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21414879/1012053)

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
REM (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (q21411489.txt) DO (
  SET "name="
  CALL :process %%a
 )
REM )>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF

:process
SET "param=%2"
IF DEFINED param SET name=%name% %1&shift&GOTO process
SET "param=%1"
SET "name=%name:~1%"
SET /a count=0
:next
IF NOT DEFINED param ECHO %name% %count%&GOTO :EOF
FOR %%e IN (Ac Al Sb As Ba Be Bi Br Cd Ca Ce Cs Cl Cr Co Cu Dy) DO IF %%e==%param:~0,2% GOTO LTR2 
FOR %%e IN (Er Gd Ga Ge Au Hf Ho In Ir Fe La Pb Li Lu Mg Mn Hg) DO IF %%e==%param:~0,2% GOTO LTR2
FOR %%e IN (Mo Nd Ni Nb Os Pd Pt Po Pr Pm Pa Ra Re Rh Rb Ru Sm) DO IF %%e==%param:~0,2% GOTO LTR2
FOR %%e IN (Sc Se Si Ag Na Sr Ta Tc Te Tb Tl Th Tm Sn Ti Yb Zn Zr) DO IF %%e==%param:~0,2% GOTO LTR2
FOR %%e IN (B C F H I N O P K S W U V Y) DO IF %%e==%param:~0,1% GOTO LTR1
SET Count=Error AT %param%
SET "param="
GOTO next

:ltr2
SET "param=%param:~1%"
:ltr1
SET /a atoms=0
:numatoms
SET "param=%param:~1%"
FOR /l %%e IN (0,1,9) DO IF "%%e"=="%param:~0,1%" (
 SET /a atoms = (10 * atoms^) + %%e
 GOTO numatoms
)
IF %atoms%==0 SET /a atoms=1
SET /a count+=atoms
GOTO next
```

Where `q21411489.txt` contains your list.

And your first calculation is wrong. Should be `75`, not `49`

Comment: I like that chem. elements are listed :-) +1

Comment: @Magoo - No, the last characters are the digit 3 and the letter O, not the number 30. So 49 is correct.

Comment: Ahh - I see the problem. It was a typo in the listing of the demo file. The last character should be capital O, not zero. The formula is correct in the body of the text. I edited the question to correct the formula in the demo file.

Answer (score 2):

I like MC ND's clever method to iterate the characters of the molecular formula and remove the lowercase letters. I dramatically simplified the remainder of the algorithm by building a mathematical formula within the first inner loop. Now the solution only requires two FOR loops instead of four.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "letters=a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z"

for /f "tokens=1,2 usebackq" %%A in ("test.txt") do (
  set "form=0"
  for /f %%C in ('cmd /d /q /u /c "echo(%%B" ^| more ^| findstr /v "%letters%"') do (
    if %%C gtr 9 (set "form=!form!+1*") else set "form=!form!%%C"
  )
  if !form:~-1! == * set "form=!form:~0,-1!"
  set /a "atomCount=!form:1*+=1+!"
  echo %%A !atomCount!
)
```

Comment: Just for aditional simplification, you can replace the `if !form:~-1!` line with just `set "form=!form!+0"` and the next line will handle it.